# "Expected token: '}'" Jquery JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an "Expected token: '}'" and when I add that token to the requested line i get "Unexpected token: '}'". Not really sure what I did wrong.
Any input is appreciated! Thanks!

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    var currentPrice = $.trim($("#ProductPrice").text());

    if(currentPrice == "%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%") 
    {
        $("#ProductPrice").css('color','black');
        $("#ProductPrice").removeClass("PriceChanged")
    }
    else
    {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop()

        if(scrollPos >= 397) {
            $("#ProductPrice").css('color','red');
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#ProductPriceWrap").offset().top
            }, 1000);

            $("#ProductPriceWrap").animate({backgroundColor: "#ff0000" });
            $("#ProductPriceWrap").animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff" });
            $("#ProductPrice").addClass("PriceChanged");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#ProductPriceWrap").animate({backgroundColor: "#ff0000" });
            $("#ProductPriceWrap").animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff" });
            $("#ProductPrice").addClass("PriceChanged");
        }
    };
```

Comment: You've missed **)** at the end. It should be **});**

Comment: It's very easy to miss issues like this. You'll save yourself a lot of strife if you use a text editor that does basic syntax highlighting and helps you indent code in a conventional manner.

Comment: @AliBZ, that, and in addition he was off by a bracket -- I cleaned up the indentation to better show it.

Comment: @AliBZ While the answer is trivial, there is a oppurtunity here to educate about how to avid this errors completely (or at least avoid being confused by them) through proper code conventions.  So it's not a useless question.

Comment: @AlexWayne I agree. I said that earlier, but now, with comments about using tools and good indentation, it could be a good question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 2):

You last closing `}` actually closes this line:

```
if(currentPrice == "%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%") 
{
```

However the expression that starts here,  never gets properly closed:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
```

So add a `});` to the end and you should be good.

---

Also, let this be a lesson for you in the value of consistent and proper indentation.  If you paste that code into http://jsbeautifier.org/ you would see the the last line is not at an even indent level as the first line.  It becomes pretty obvious then where the problem is.

If the code within that callback function was all indented, you probably would have noticed this and it would have been a quick fix.

*So today you learned the value of consistent and proper indentation.*